# Input value is not respecting padding and breaking container

Tags: html, css, input

I'm doing a contact form with a `<input type="submit">` to submit the form. I set a padding to my input and I have a **large text value**.

My design is responsive. In mobile my input is set to the 100% of the container, but the text value in the input is not respecting the padding and the width. The text value is not going into two lines and I can't see the complete text.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this problem will be welcome!

**Why I'm using an `<input>` instead a `<button>` or `<a href>`?** Is because I'm using my HTML to create a custom Contact Form 7 in a Wordpress site, and CF7 uses an `<input type="submit">` to send the messages.

Comment: can you post your form code and css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add CSS rule `white-space: normal` to the button. In browsers, `<input>` defaults to `whitespace: pre` whereas `<button>` defaults to `white-space: normal`.